# Angular - how to check length of Array in *ngFor, when using Async pipe?

Tags: angular

I have:

```
<mat-toolbar-row *ngFor="let idp of Idps | async; last as isLast">
```

and I need to access the length of it for these:

```
 <button [disabled]="(Idps| async)?.length===1" [ngClass]="{'disabledBtn': !(Idps | async)?.length > 1}"
```

this sadly does not work, I managed to make that syntax work only here:

```
{{ (Idps | async)?.length }}
```

if I put this in my HTML, it will show on screen the length, but I cannot find the right syntax to use for my `[disabled]` and `[ngClass]` tags

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use local variable from NgForOf directive ("count")

```
<mat-toolbar-row *ngFor="let idp of Idps | async; last as isLast; count as count">
```

[Here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) you can find all the variables available for NgForOf directive

Comment: It worth to add that full list of available variables can be found at https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables